# como buscar en un array la suma de dos elementos y comparar a una variable javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función con dos argumentos `function sumArray(array, n)`, **"array"** es un array de números ordenados y **"n"** es el resultado de la suma de cualquiera de dos números de ese array.

el enunciado del ejercicio es este:

```js
// La función llamada 'sumArray' recibe como argumento un arreglo de números ordenados llamado 'array' y un número
// entero llamado 'n' y debe devolver true si alguna combinación de dos números cualesquiera del arreglo sumados
// dan n, y devuelva false si ninguna combinación de dos números sumados da como resultado el número n.
// Ej:
// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13)  debería devolver true ya que 2 + 11 = 13
// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14)  debería devolver false ya que no es posible sumar 14 con dos números del arreglo
// Pista: Podes usar bucles/ciclos anidados
// Aclaración: No es válido sumar el mismo número dos veces
// Ej:
// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 4)  Si bien 2 + 2 = 4 no está permitido sumar el mismo número dos veces
// por lo tanto también debería devolver false en este caso

function sumArray(array, n) {
  let arrayB = array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
  let result = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < arrayB.length; index++) {
   var arrayb = arrayB[index];
  }

  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] === arrayb){
      return false;
    }else{
      result[i] = parseint(array[i])+parseint(arrayb);
    }
  }
  for (let e = 0; e < result.length; e++) {
    if(result[e] === n){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    } 
  }
};
```

Comment: Hola, si el array está ordenado, para que necesitas crear un arrayB y además desordenado?

Comment: Esa solución la puedes lograr facilmente con 2 arrays anidados... pero porque complicar el problema? para que quieres un arrayB desordenado? la segunda variable `arrayb` solo contendrá el valor del ultimo elemento del array... le asignas muchos valores, pero no haces nada con ellos...- hasta que el ultimo sobreescribe todos los demás.

Comment: por que necesitaba que no se sumen los numeros iguales, asi que lo unico que se ocurrio era desordenarlo y tratar de sumar

Answer (score 1):

La solución mas simple sería:

```js
function sumArray(array, num){
  for(let i=0; i<array.length-2; i++){
    for(let j=i+1; j<=array.length-1; j++){
      if((array[i]+array[j]) === num){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

console.log(sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13)); // debería devolver true ya que 2 + 11 = 13 
console.log(sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14)); //Deberia devolver false porque no hay combinacion que sume 14
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo la solución a la que yo llegue fue de hacer dos for anidados, ambos for recorren el mismo array solo que el primero toma un valor  lo va comparando contra todos las valores del sigueinte for, de esta forma cada valor del array es comparado contra todos los valores y si se topa con el mismo valor lo salta, si no es el mismo valor suma los valores del array uno con subindice i y el otro con j después de eso compara si es igual al valor n si es igual retorna un true si ningún valor fue retornado al terminar el for retorna un false.

```
    function sumArray(array, n){
        let suma;
        for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
             for(j=0;j<array.length;j++){
                   if(array[i] != array[j]){
                       suma = array[i] + array[j];
                       if(suma == n){
                           return true;
                       }
                   }
             }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Suponiendo que no haya dos números iguales en el arreglo, puedes evitar comparar `arreglo[i] == arreglo [j]` si al segundo for lo inicias en `i + 1` (`for (j = i + 1; ...`)

Comment: Muchas Gracias.